# Should a lease letter state that it supersedes the lease itself?

Tags: rental-property

I am signing a lease where there are various changes that are required to it, the landlord refuses to change the lease but instead has issued a latter with the changes on it. The letter make no mention that it supersedes the lease in any way and also states "This agreement does not constitute a variation of the terms of the Lease, which shall continue in full force and effect notwithstanding the terms of this agreement."

Doesn't that mean whatever is in the letter means nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, under those facts and circumstances, the letter should constitute an amendment of the lease and supersede it, but it is written in a way that is ambiguous on its face, and is certainly not ideal.